# Decoupling Identity Data from App Layer in a Multi-Tenant Architecture

Tags: c#, database, microservices, domain-driven-design

I have a "complex" project structure and I'm facing challenges in decoupling data, especially TenantId and UserId, between the Identity system and the App layer.

The project structure is as follows:

```
└───FooBar
    ├───FooBar.sln
    ├───src
    │   ├───App
    │   │   ├───Api
    │   │   │   └───FooBar.App.Api
    │   │   ├───Core
    │   │   │   ├───FooBar.App.Application
    │   │   │   ├───FooBar.App.Infrastructure
    │   │   │   └───FooBar.App.Domain
    │   │   ├───Data
    │   │   │   └───FooBar.Identity.Persistence
    │   │   └───Worker
    │   ├───Common
    │   │   ├───FooBar.Common
    │   │   ├───FooBar.Common.Application
    │   │   ├───FooBar.Common.DependencyInjection
    │   │   ├───FooBar.Common.Domain
    │   │   ├───FooBar.Common.Environment
    │   │   ├───FooBar.Common.Events
    │   │   ├───FooBar.Common.Infrastructure
    │   │   └───FooBar.Common.Localize
    │   ├───Data
    │   │   ├───FooBar.Data.OutboxPublisher
    │   │   └───FooBar.Data.Persistence
    │   ├───Identity
    │   │   ├───Api
    │   │   │   └───FooBar.Identity.Api
    │   │   ├───Core
    │   │   │   ├───FooBar.Identity.Application
    │   │   │   ├───FooBar.Identity.Domain
    │   │   │   ├───FooBar.Identity.Environment
    │   │   │   └───FooBar.Identity.Infrastructure
    │   │   ├───Data
    │   │   │   └───FooBar.Identity.Persistence
    │   │   └───Worker
    │   ├───Integration
    │   │   ├───Email
    │   │   ├───Payment
    │   │   ├───SMS
    │   │   └───Worker
    │   └───Subscription
    │       ├───Api
    │       │   └───FooBar.App.Api
    │       ├───Core
    │       │   ├───FooBar.App.Application
    │       │   └───FooBar.App.Infrastructure
    │       ├───Data
    │       │   └───FooBar.Identity.Persistence
    │       └───Worker
    └───test
        ├───App
        ├───Common
        ├───Data
        ├───Identity
        ├───Integration
        └───Subscription
```

The key concern is how to ensure data isolation based on TenantId in the App layer, and how to make UserId available for services like an AuditService.

One way I thought about is emitting an event when a user registers, which then creates a row in the App DB containing minimal data about the tenant, possibly just the Primary Key.

The biggest challenge is that I'd like to keep the Identity database and other databases separate. However, since Identity contains key information needed for index partitioning and other operations, I find myself tightly coupled to it.

Are there best practices or alternative approaches for decoupling this kind of data? Your insights would be valuable.